# Fade in images after they have loaded

Tags: jquery, image, load

I found this code to achieve the desired effect and tried it on JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/7F9tY/366/

It seems to work in that it fades the image in after it has loaded. Then I tried it in a webpage and it didn't work the same way, loading the image first rather than fading it in. Although sometimes it seemed like it was fading in at the same time as it loaded.

Is there a more reliable way of achieving this, preferably by amending this code if possible?

`$("#image").ready(function(){
      $("#preload").fadeIn(1000);
});`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The only reliable way to `fadeIn()` an image that is in your actual HTML markup is to set an `onload` handler in the HTML markup like this:

```
<div id="image">
    <img id="preload" onload="fadeIn(this)" src="https://photos.smugmug.com/photos/i-NLws86p/0/b356e43a/L/i-NLws86p-S.jpg" style="display:none;" />
</div>

<script>
// this function must be defined in the global scope
window.fadeIn = function(obj) {
    $(obj).fadeIn(1000);
}
</script>
```

Working demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/X82zY/

Doing is this way, you don't need to give each image an id or class.  Just set the style and the event handler in the markup.

The reason you have to put the event handler in the markup is that if you wait until your page's javascript runs, it may be too late.  The image may already be loaded (particularly if it's in the browser cache) and thus you may have missed the `onload` event.  If you put the handler in the HTML markup, you will not miss the `onload` event because the handler is assigned before the image starts loading.

If you don't want to put event handlers in the javascript, then you can do something like this where you use a placeholder for the image in the actual HTML and you use javascript to create the actual image tags and insert them and pull the image URL from the placeholder:

```
<div>
    <span class="fadeIn" data-src="https://photos.smugmug.com/photos/i-NLws86p/0/b356e43a/L/i-NLws86p-S.jpg"></span>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fadeIn").each(function() {
        var src = $(this).data("src");
        if (src) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.style.display = "none";
            img.onload = function() {
                $(this).fadeIn(1000);
            };
            $(this).append(img);            
            img.src = src;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/BNFqM/

The first option will get your images loaded a little quicker (because image loading starts immediately upon page parsing), but the second option gives you more programmatic control over the process.

Comment: Thanks. I had a bit of trouble with option 1 in terms of other jquery not executing correctly. I'll go with option 2 :)

Comment: @Andy - that's odd.  Option 1 has nothing to do with other jQuery.  Other jQuery would still go where it typically does in a `$(document).ready()` function.  I'm glad option 2 works for you, but option 1 could too if you want to figure out why something else wasn't working.

Comment: Worked that time, no idea what I did first.

Comment: @jfriend00 Does the 'style=display:none' in your option 1 negatively impact the SEO, if we have the image name with meaningful slug? I guess so, but not sure.

Comment: @Ethan - SEO rules are not entirely disclosed, but since search engines for the most part don't run your Javascript (most of what they see is your initial HTML), it's unlikely the search engine would even know that you create an image that is `display: none`.  As far as the search engine knows, there's not even an image there.  If you want the search engine to see your images, then they should be present in the raw HTML rather than added via JS.  But, the images don't generally play much of a role in your SEO anyway since their content is hard to discern other than `alt` and `title` tags.

Comment: @jfriend00 Actually google is using image names now for the SEO, as I understand. Assuming it's an ecommerce page, say for a product whose meaningful slug will be 'emsa-vacuum-jug-green' and this slug exists in both page url and image name, then having the 'display:none' will be at a loss (option #1). If at best google doesn't think that we are 'stuffing' keywords in the image name with the <slug>.jpg but display:none, then also the image name will not contribute to the keywords in the page. So, effectively, it's better to have search engines know there's a meaningful image existing there.

Comment: From option #1, you can remove the 'style='display:none"' and change the 2nd javascript line to: $(obj).hide().fadeIn(1000). That's better from SEO perspective.

Comment: @ethan22 - then it may briefly flash visible as it loads before the js runs.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for that info, I didn't notice that. I wanted to ask you another question: solely with javascript ie without jquery, how will the onLoad routine be if I don't want any fading?

Comment: @Ethan - if you don't want fading, what is the point of the onload handler?  What is it you want to do there?

Comment: @jfriend00 I want to avoid the gradual display of the image, but in one shot once downloaded. (Images are in the range of 40-140KB) Don't want the fanciness of fading. And preferable if it's without jQuery.

Comment: @Ethan - then you can make it visible in plain javascript with `this.style.display = "inline";`

Comment: Useful, thanks! Your fiddle still "works" but the image you used now results in 404. Maybe worth updating for others who stumble across this and don't think to sub in a new image url.

Comment: @Skipjack - Fixed.

Comment: It seems the first example only works for me when I define the function earlier than the DOM element, so I added a script tag in the head for it.

Comment: @AdamHunterPeck - What browser?

Comment: @jfriend00 Current Chrome. I usually have my script tag with all my functions at the end of my document after the body is closed. I just tried with the script tag as the last thing within the body, but it still threw an Uncaught ReferenceError (not defined). Maybe it's because I'm working on the file on my computer locally, so the image loads immediately before the page has time to read through all the functions?

Answer (score 14):

**Pure java script and CSS solution:**

Using the transitions effect with opactiy.

```js
const images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (let image of images) {
  image.addEventListener("load", fadeImg);
  image.style.opacity = "0";
}

function fadeImg () {
  this.style.transition = "opacity 2s";
  this.style.opacity = "1";
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Lunch_atop_a_Skyscraper.jpg" width="190">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Lenna_%28test_image%29.png" width="190">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Mandel_zoom_00_mandelbrot_set.jpg" width="190">
```

Comment: Good approach. Only keep in mind that css transition doesn't work in IE9 or lower version.

Comment: This still relies on 'load'

Answer (score 4):

## html

```
<div id="image">
    <img id="preload" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7227/7007769551_3b5b1640ea_b.jpg" style="display:none;" />
</div>
```

## javascript

.ready() does not fire they way you think it does, see the ['load'](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) jQuery event handler

```
$("#preload").load(function(evt){
      $(this).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: pay close attention to the restrictions on .load() further down the documentation

Comment: This probably won't work in some browsers after the image is in the browser cache because the image will finish loading before you javascript runs, thus you will never see the load event.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah, that's in the documentation on .load()

Answer (score 4):

Maybe interesting for people who find this question and use angular.js:

I've written a small directive which does the job quite well.

JS:

```
.directive('imgFadeInOnload', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attr) {
        element.css('opacity', 0);
        element.css('-moz-transition', 'opacity 2s');
        element.css('-webkit-transition', 'opacity 2s');
        element.css('-o-transition', 'opacity 2s');
        element.css('transition', 'opacity 2s');
        element.bind("load", function () {
          element.css('opacity', 1);
        });
        element.attr('src', attr.imgFadeInOnload);
      }
    };
  });
```

HTML:

```
<img img-fade-in-onload="{{imgSrc}}" src="">
```

By setting `src` not in the HTML but in the directive code the problem mentioned by jfriend00 (handler is attached after the `onload` is fired) is solved.

Comment: I intend to give this a try using angular.js - thanks for posting.

Comment: Best Solution when using Angular. Fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

`fadeIn` should be called after the image has loaded. Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mYYym/

Comment: How could I make that work for multiple images on the same page? I don't want to repeat the same code and give each image a separate ID, otherwise it seems like only the first image loads.

Comment: This probably won't work in some browsers after the image is in the browser cache because the image will finish loading before you javascript runs, thus you will never see the load event.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a css transition and javascript solution based on @jfriend00's answer and similar to the approach of @Robbendebiene:

- provides fallbacks to display the image if js is turned off
- only the one bit of inline javascript is required `onload="this.style.opacity=1"`
- all animation is CSS, no need for jQuery or complex javascript

```css
img.fadein {
  opacity: 1;  /* fallback in case of no js */
  transition: opacity 500ms ease;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.js img.fadein {
  opacity: 0; /* start with hidden image if we have js */
}
```

```html
<!-- use moderinr to provide the "js" class on the html element -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<img class="fadein" onload="this.style.opacity=1" src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/1500/">
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a modern compact non-jquery version 8 years later (like me). If the inserted code below doesnt render correctly, try the fiddle below, it works

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s6nvb95z/

```js
fadeIn = e => e.style.opacity = 1;
```

```css
img {
   width: 500px; // Just for this example
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
    <img onload="fadeIn(this)" src="https://live.staticflickr.com/4672/39593615781_fe8e95a6fb_k.jpg" />
</div>
```