# Run JS after image is loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, animation, load

I have a DIV with a background image. The image path changes based on the $_GET array.

```
<div id="background-img" style="background: url('elements/<?php if (empty($_GET['p'])){ echo 'home'; } else { echo $_GET['p'];} ?>.jpg') no-repeat fixed center center; background-size:cover;"></div>
```

I want this DIV's opacity to change from 0-1 using a transition

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#background-img').css('opacity', '0');
        $('#background-img').animate({opacity: 1}, 2000);
})
```

Now this is all great and dandy. 
BUT I only want this animation to happen when the image is loaded (the images is quite large). There are other animations I also want to run, but only after that image has loaded.

I've tried doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.fadein').css('opacity', '0');
        $('#background-img').css('opacity', '0');
        $('#header').css('opacity', '0');
});
$('#background-img').load(function(){
        $('#background-img').animate({opacity: 1}, 2000);
        $('#header').delay(1000).animate({opacity: 1}, 2000);
        $('.fadein').delay(2000).animate({opacity: 1}, 2000); 
});
```

But it didn't work. The animations simply don't run.
I am running jquery, and happy to use that to solve the problem.
It seems like such a simple thing, but I can't seem to find out how to solve it.
Is

Once I figure it out I also intend to make some "loading" gif animate in and out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/start-jquery-after-image-loads

or this might help: [Fade in images after they have loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845774/fade-in-images-after-they-have-loaded) `:)`

http://jsfiddle.net/hmeev/

**code**

```
$(window).load(function(){
        $('#background-img').animate({opacity: 1}, 2000);
        $('#header').delay(1000).animate({opacity: 1}, 2000);
        $('.fadein').delay(2000).animate({opacity: 1}, 2000); 
});
```

Comment: @toms Glad it helped +1 to you as well! `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Use .load on the image itself.

```
$('#bg').ready(function(){
    $('#bg').css({opacity:"1"});
});
```

Here http://jsfiddle.net/UA94f/

Comment: Would that work on a div with a background image? Won't this just wait for the div itself to load or would that wait for EVEYTHING in the div to load?

Comment: Yes it will wait for the image. Please check the fiddle I provided. And try to use an image of large size to get that waiting time.