Show a slight delay with dynamically displayed images
I have a page that dynamically displays images when various buttons are clicked. All works perfectly.
However, I would like to have each newly created image appear on the page with a slight delay, maybe also a very slight opacity transition, to give the impression of images being loaded in a more "natural" way, rather than have the whole page appear in a jarring jump.
The question is, where in the repeat loop would this go? How do I implement this with dynamic images as I can't add a delay or transition to something that doesn't exist in the DOM? Is the best method a settimeout() function or CSS transition or both?
Looking for pointers, maybe even an online tutorial.
 for (let i = startIndex; i < finishLength; i++) {
    const picDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
    const displayPic = document.createElement("IMG");
    /// add id's, class, alt, src, insert into div, etc
    document.getElementById("displayArea").appendChild(picDiv);
    // Do something here, or elsewhere, to make each image/div appear with a slight delay
  }


"as I can't add a delay or transition to something that doesn't exist in the DOM" sure you can.  css is applies to newly created elements.   Add a transition / animation to "img" (or, better, give them a class and apply to that)

Potential existing solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24410656/2181514

you don't take into account the loading time of images? even in the case of users with a bad connection?  --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode

You can use a CSS transition:
img { /* or maybe images with some class, if you don't want all images to do this*/
  opacity: 0;
}

.faded-in {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
}

You can then add toggle the faded-in class in JavaScript when the image is done loading:
const displayArea = document.querySelector("#displayArea");
for (let i = startIndex; i < finishLength; i++) {
  const displayPic = document.createElement("IMG");
  // add id's, class, alt, src, insert into div, etc
  displayPic.addEventListener("load", fadeIn);
  displayArea.appendChild(displayPic);
}

function fadeIn(event) {
  event.target.classList.toggle("faded-in");
}

Play with the transition time so that it feels fast but not jarring.
See this


const displayArea = document.querySelector("#displayArea");
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const displayPic = document.createElement("IMG");
  displayPic.src = "https://picsum.photos/200";
  displayPic.alt = "";
  displayPic.addEventListener("load", fadeIn);
  displayArea.appendChild(displayPic);
}

function fadeIn(event) {
  event.target.classList.toggle("faded-in");
}
img {
  opacity: 0;
}

.faded-in {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
}
<div id="displayArea">
</div>



